# Getting text of parent, child and their child

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

```
<avis>
<numeroseao>1331795</numeroseao>
<numero>61628-3435560</numero>
<organisme>Ville de Québec</organisme>
<fournisseurs>
  <fournisseur>
    <nomorganisation>APEL ASSOCIATION POUT DU LA MARAISNORD</nomorganisation>
    <adjudicataire>1</adjudicataire>
    <montantsoumis>0.000000</montantsoumis>
    <montantssoumisunite>0</montantssoumisunite>
    <montantcontrat>89732.240000</montantcontrat>
    <montanttotalcontrat>0.000000</montanttotalcontrat>
  </fournisseur>
</fournisseurs>
</avis>
```

So there is avis, avis has fournisseurs, fournisseurs has further nodes. How do I get these values to a data frame?

I am using the below code

```
element_tree = ET.parse('D:\\python_script\\temp2\\AvisRevisions_20200201_20200229.xml')
root = element_tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall('.//avis/*/*/*'):
```

or

```
for child in root.findall('.//avis/*'):
```

but it only gets me either the parent nodes or child nodes, not all of them.

Comment: "but it only gets me either the parent nodes or child nodes, not all of them." I notice you have tried `'.//avis/*'` (with one `/*`) and `'.//avis/*/*/*'` (with three `/*`s). Perhaps you can think of an alternative that's in between those two? Did you try that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you're using Pandas then you should tag that, and you should show the code that you use inside the loop to try to create the Dataframe that you mentioned. It's not clear to me why you're writing a loop at all, if you only want to create one Dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is not flat it might cause issues when you import the xml directly into pandas. In this scenario a library like `pandas_read_xml` might be useful:

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml(xml)
df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)  # this should get you the structure you want
```

In the line above, the xml variable is your "AvisRevisions_20200201_20200229.xml" file.

---

For a flatter structure you could use Pandas as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath="//fournisseurs")
```

If you are looking for the entire "avis" section, you can replace the xpath parameter by:

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath="//avis")
```

From this, pandas should create the dataframe with appropriate columns. Here is a link to the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<avis>
<numeroseao>1331795</numeroseao>
<numero>61628-3435560</numero>
<organisme>Ville de Québec</organisme>
<fournisseurs>
  <fournisseur>
    <nomorganisation>APEL ASSOCIATION POUT DU LA MARAISNORD</nomorganisation>
    <adjudicataire>1</adjudicataire>
    <montantsoumis>0.000000</montantsoumis>
    <montantssoumisunite>0</montantssoumisunite>
    <montantcontrat>89732.240000</montantcontrat>
    <montanttotalcontrat>0.000000</montanttotalcontrat>
  </fournisseur>
</fournisseurs>
</avis>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

data = []
fournisseur = root.find('.//fournisseur')
data.append({e.tag:e.text for e in fournisseur})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```